# A simple property of outer measure

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

I'm struggle with proof about statement as follow.
I tried to prove. But I think that it doesn't work..

---

**PROPERTY:**

Assume that $m^{*}(A)<\infty$. Then, $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists \mathcal{I}_{\varepsilon}=\left(I_{k}^{\varepsilon}\right)$ countable collection of open intervals with $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_{k}^{\varepsilon} \supset A$ such
that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} l\left(I_{k}^{\varepsilon}\right)<m^{*}(A)+\varepsilon$.

Comment: What is your definition of outer measure? This is immediate from the standard definition.

Comment: Here is definition of outer measure. let $\mathcal{J}=\lbrace J_{k}~:~k\in\mathbb{N}\rbrace$ be a countable collection of open intervals with $A \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} J_{k}$. Then, outer measure is defined as $\displaystyle m^{*}(A)=\underset{\mathcal{J}}{\inf} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} l(J_{k})$.

Comment: In fact, I can not understand why the given property is follow immediatly..

Comment: Well, $m^*(A)+\varepsilon>m^*(A)$, so what does the definition of infimum tell you now.

Comment: I'm sorry.. As my understanding, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} l\left(I_{k}^{\varepsilon}\right)<\underset{\mathcal{I}}{\inf} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} l(I_{k})<\underset{\mathcal{I}}{\inf} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} l(I_{k})+\varepsilon$. I can not understand the first inequality..

Comment: Well, that first inequality is false. Forget everything about measures and series for a second. If I have a bounded below, non-empty set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $x=\inf A$, then can you see why for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is an $a\in A$ with $a<x+\varepsilon$?

Comment: Yes, I know that is a property of infimum.

Comment: Then apply this to the current situation and you're done.

Comment: Now I can understand! Thanks!! Have a nice day. I want you to be free from Corona 19.